# passing value of text box to href in smarty

Tags: smarty

A want to pass value of text box to  href="somepage.php start=textbox1.text end = textbox1.text" in smarty without use of java script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please reword this or give examples? As written, it's not quite clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Smarty is simply a templating engine to aid with the server-side generation of the markup. It can't do what JavaScript can do.